# asp.net web application request timeout

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a problem with my asp.net web application. During the test process, there was no problem but after a lot of users started to use application, it gets timeout.. Where should i check for this problem?

Comment: I encourage you start reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer this question. You haven't even mentioned where the timeout is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's... not a lot of detail. :/

You have a resource bottleneck *somewhere*. That could be a DB connection, the web-server itself, or the physical machine resources (i.e. memory). It could be some IDisposable object you aren't releasing, I've seen similar behaviour from an app full of statics which shouldn't have been - basically it could be anything.

You need to start applying diagnostic tools: [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972204.aspx), a DB profiler like MS SQL Profiler if you have one, simple logging at IIS and application level, etc...